# O que acontece com a memória quando "realloc()" realoca um bloco de memória para um valor menor que o original?

Tags: c, memória, alocação, gerenciamento-de-memória, malloc

Supondo que eu aloque uma matriz dinâmica de 10 `int`s e atribua alguns valores valores a ela, depois eu uso a função `realloc()` para realocar a matriz para 3 `int`s, o que acontece com os outros 7 `int`s, eles serão liberados da memoria pela função `realloc()` ou a memoria irá vazar?

Outra pergunta: Neste caso em especifico faz sentido atribuir o retorno de `realloc()` para uma variável temporária, afinal eu não estou requisitando memoria nova, mas sim diminuindo a memoria que eu já tinha alocado.

Aqui está um exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int *values = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    values[i] = i;
  }

  int *tempValues = realloc(values, 3 * sizeof(int));

  if(tempValues != NULL) {
    values = tempValues;
  }

  free(values);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> o que acontece com os outros 7 `int`s, eles serão liberados da memoria pela função `realloc()` ou a memoria irá vazar?

Será liberado. Tecnicamente a memória não irá vazar, mas nada garante que a liberação provocará o reuso deste espaço. Então mesmo que não exista um vazamento pode haver um desperdício dessa memória, por isso é raro alguém fazer um, `realloc()` diminuindo o tamanho, já que isso só é útil para porções grandes, e também porque é comum precisar aumentar o número de itens logo depois de reduzir.

Em linguagens de mais alto nível costuma ter estruturas que lidam bem com isso abstratamente e faz o que for melhor sem o programador ter que interferir (costuma poder fazer opcionalmente), em C o comum é alguém usar alguma biblioteca que dá isto ou que a pessoa crie uma estrutura que lide melhor com essa forma. Fazendo isso ou mesmo ainda mexendo manualmente é comum ter uma estratégia de reaproveitamento dos itens e o `realloc()` é menos aplicado solto em código da aplicação do que imagina. Por incrível que pareça costuma ser melhor desperdiçar um pouco de espaço. Só vale a pena diminuir se você tiver certeza que não precisará crescer de novo e o ganho seja expressivo e necessário.

O `realloc()` é mais usado para crescer o objeto, porque em geral realmente haverá uma realocação. Diminuir o tamanho do objeto não provocará uma realocação.

#### Fragmentação de memória

Uma das formas que isto acontece é justamente liberar uma porção de memória (`realloc()` é só uma das técnicas) e ela ficar sem uso porque outros objetos podem ser maiores que esse espaço liberado. Isso é ruim, mas não é trágico, e é mais comum do que as pensam. De fato a não ser que esteja em um dispositivo com memória muito escassa não compensa tentar economizar essa memória (pra tudo tem exceção). O exemplo citado provavelmente não compensa, você economizar alguns poucos bytes e que talvez nunca seja usado de novo. Mas pode ser usado e ser pior.

Tem um outro tipo de fragmentação que é o fato dos objetos que costumam ser usados juntos estarem em locais diferentes. Se cabe um objeto neste espaço liberado mas outro relacionado não cabe ele será colocado em outro ponto da memória, distante deste, quando for acessar e os objetos estiverem separados terá dois acessos e provavelmente estarão fora do cache. A fragmentação piora a localidade de referência. Quando os objetos estão juntos é provável que sejam acessados de forma mais eficiente, quando eles são relacionados.

Você troca um pouco de memória por performance.

> Neste caso em especifico faz sentido atribuir o retorno de `realloc()` para uma variável temporária

Faz sentido neste caso restrito. Se fosse outro caso eu não sei, depende de contexto. Vamos dizer que isto fosse uma função que faz algo de forma mais realista e recebe um ponteiro para um objeto e reduz o seu tamanho. Você não poderia usar o `free()`, certo?

Se é certo que está reduzindo o tamanho não pode haver falha. Nada na especificação diz que não pode falhar, mas sabemos que não falha, até porque se não fosse assim provavelmente quase nunca deveria realocar para reduzir o tamanho, porque o custo seria alto demais. Se está fazendo em C geralmente está procurando performance. Em implementações normais você pode contar que não haverá falha e não precisa atribuir nada extra ou testar se a redução funcionou (em tese o código não será 100% portável, mas na prática é, seria o mesmo que o pessoal fala que *stack* e *heap* são detalhes de implementação, mas na prática todo mundo desenvolve pensando que eles existem e tem a semântica universalmente conhecida). Alguma guarda pode ser interessante se for usar esse comportamento não documentado e souber que o código poderá rodar em qualquer compilador, até os mais "doidos".

Só tome cuidado para não usar a variável original depois de dar o `realloc()` e antes de reatribuí-la, como fez corretamente, portanto se usar variável temporária use sempre esse padrão de reatribuir logo após o teste.

## Conclusão

Se quer saber mais leia a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc). Ela não é oficial, mas é como se fosse, é onde há curadoria de bons profissionais de C/C++.

O exemplo não é bom para mostrar como as coisas acontecem no mundo real. Ele serve para mostrar o mecanismo, só tenha claro essa diferença para não reproduzir o mesmo comportamento em código real.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Não sei se vou conseguir responder ao seu agrado, mas vamos lá..

> O que acontece com a memoria quando realloc realoca um bloco de
>   memoria para um valor menor que o original?

Simplesmente o `realloc()` vai fazer um `free()` no que foi reduzido, marcando assim que a memória liberada fica disponível pra outros usos.

> Faz sentido atribuir o retorno de realloc para uma variável
>   temporária, afinal eu não estou requisitando memoria nova, mas sim
>   diminuindo a memoria que eu já tinha alocado.

Checando a definição do [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/), o `realloc()` tem como retorno:
*"A pointer to the reallocated memory block, which may be either the same as ptr or a new location."*

**E porque você deve usar a variável temporária para checar?**

Se olhar a referência que passei acima, veras também a seguinte afirmação:

*"A null-pointer indicates that the function failed to allocate storage, and thus the block pointed by ptr was not modified."*

Em outras palavras se o `realloc()` falhar você ainda poderá usar o bloco original, através da sua variável `*values`, diferentemente do que poderia acontecer se você não usasse a variável temporária, e setasse o `realloc()` direto pra ela, e a mesma falhasse, retornando um `NULL` e assim você bagunça todo o programa.

Ao meu ver não há problema em criar a variável temporária, você deve!