# Qual é o comportamento esperado de realloc()?

Tags: c, alocação, gerenciamento-de-memória, dinâmico

Tenho algumas dúvidas sobre a função `realloc()`. A utilidade dela no meu entendimento é permitir acrescentar/remover bytes da maneira menos destrutiva possível (no que se refere ao conteúdo já inicializado) a/de uma região previamente alocada e de ponto inicial fixo (apesar que esse "fixo" é relativo, como se verá). Em outras palavras, ela realoca um espaço previamente alocado por `malloc()` ou `calloc()` (duas funções cuja diferença básica é que uma aloca bytes contíguos da memória sem inicializá-los, já a outra inicializa/limpa os bytes alocados).

Achei [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432581/357), ela ajuda mas não tem o mesmo foco.

Primeira dúvida: `realloc()` pode ser usada tanto para aumentar como para diminuir o espaço previamente alocado? Nesse caso, o que acontece com o conteúdo do espaço que se manteve? E com o conteúdo do espaço "novo"?

Segundo, vou descrever a imagem abaixo que é referente aos casos em que `realloc()` é usada para aumentar o espaço alocado, a fim de ajudar no entendimento da função.

Quando há espaço suficiente, `realloc()` aloca estendendo o espaço alocado anteriormente e retorna um ponteiro apontando para o mesmo lugar que foi passado à função. Quando não há espaço suficiente, ele aloca em outra região em que haja espaço e copia os dados previamente alocados para o trecho correspondente do novo espaço alocado, e também retorna um novo endereço, diferente do ponteiro anterior.

[image: Comportamento de realloc()]

Então por conta disso estou deduzindo que `realloc()`, quando usada para aumentar o espaço alocado, não destrói o conteúdo pré-existente, porém não garante que ele permaneça na mesma região da memória em que estava. E que também não oferece nenhuma garantia de inicialização/limpeza do espaço que foi acrescentado, que se for necessária terá que ser feita posteriormente.

Esse entendimento está correto?

Comment: Em tempo, talvez fosse melhor mudar o título para qual o comportamento esperado em relação ao conteúdo previamente alocado, ou qual o comportamento quando usada para aumentar o espaço, mas queria focar de maneira ampla (sic) no comportamento geral da função.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> realloc() pode tanto aumentar como diminuir o espaço previamente alocado?

Não. Ele aloca outro espaço maior ou menor e depois descarta o espaço anterior. Pelo menos deve ser entendido assim. Pode até usar um mesmo espaço mas não deve contar com isso. Como ele vai fazer é detalhe de implementação, tudo pode acontecer além do que está na especificação, que não diz nada em específico como ele deve funcionar além do mínimo necessário. É simples assim.

Você pode observar o comportamento descrito na pergunta em algumas implementações, mas como não pode garantir que isso acontecerá, nem mesmo em outra versão da mesma implementação, faça de conta que isso não acontece.

A destruição do conteúdo antigo não existe. Não é proibido, mas não é exigido e a filosofia do C indica que nunca acontecerá em uma implementação tradicional. Há liberação daquela área de memória para ser reutilizada, só isso.

Ele funciona como se desse um `malloc()` e um `free()`, embora possa ter alguma otimização que seja melhor que usar ambos no lugar do `realloc()`, inclusive ele pode não mexer na alocação, que é uma enorme otimização. Gerenciamento de memória é bem caro. Por isso um GC pode ser mais performático, em algumas situações, de gerenciar alocação manualmente.

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc). Ali diz que há duas situações possíveis: ficar no mesmo lugar; ou mover e copiar os dados. Só isso. Só o que pode contar. Se fizer algo mais é liberalidade da implementação.

Isso é retirado da especificação. Dá para olhá-la, mas ela costuma ser mais difícil de entender.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: _"Destruição do conteúdo antigo não existe"_ Acho que eu quis dizer limpeza. Mas mesmo assim acredito que está implícito que quando o espaço é reduzido a parte final do que estava previamente alocado se perde. Ou estou errado em contar sempre que seja passado um ponteiro apontando para o início de um espaço? Talvez não esteja considerando a possibilidade de passar o "meio" de uma região (ponteiro incrementado) para realloc. Isso é possível?

Comment: Em nenhuma situação é para apagar nada, mas pode acontecer, até mesmo por alguma otimização em situação específica. Não há definição clara de onde será o novo ponteiro que ele devolverá pode até mesmo ser em um local no meio de onde havia uma alocação que agora não existirá mais. Não que isso seja comum, mas pode. Você só pode contar que receberá um ponteiro (pode ser um inválido se algo der errado). Quando fala em novo, pode ser igual ao antigo.

Comment: A pergunta que fiz foi, em relação ao ponteiro que será passado a realloc, pode ser um ponteiro para o "meio" de um espaço alocado? Realloc assume que se trata de um ponteiro apontando para o início de um espaço alocado e se não for o comportamento ficaria portanto indefinido? Vou conferir na documentação. P.S.: Entendi que sim.

Comment: Ele não pode sobrepor uma área já alocada, a não ser que ele saiba que será liberada e queira otimizar isso. Não que seja comum acontecer, mas pode. Em algo que continuará alocado não pode porque sobreporia algo existente. Mas nada tem a ver com meio de nada, no início também teria o mesmo problema. O `realloc()` só pode apontar para uma área livre, e se está livre não existe início ou meio, é só uma área livre, ele pode fazer o que quiser.

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal. Perguntei se poderia por exemplo incrementar ou decrementar um ponteiro para uma área mallocada e passar para `realloc()`. Pelo que entendi logo no início da documentação, isso dá comportamento indefinido porque ela espera (uso normal) que seja passado um ponteiro para o início de uma área mallocada.

Comment: Não sei se entendo o que quer dizer. Você pode acessar toda memória disponível para o processo.

Comment: Pensei num ponteiro para um array que foi feito malloc(). Posso incrementar esse ponteiro (fugir do que ele realmente estava apontando) e passar para realloc. O realloc pelo que entendi tem a expectativa que seja passado para ele um ponteiro para um início de área mallocada, se eu passar um ponteiro que aponta para além desse início vai dar comportamento indefinido. Era essa a minha dúvida. Em tempo: esclareci que me referia a realocar da maneira menos destrutiva possível no que se refere ao conteúdo inicializado (não ao comportamento de mudar de área de memória), mas a resposta ainda vale.

Comment: Você pode fazer o que quiser, C deixa, é responsabilidade sua fazer certo. Ela só garante as operações que ela mesma faz, o que você manda fazer é feito, ando certo ou não. Se você passar um ponteiro que não é o início de um bloco alocado qualquer coisa pode acontecer.